# php: what symbols such as <, > etc should be replaced to display a string on the html page the same way as it was typed

Tags: php, html, string

A user types any text in the textarea on html page. The string is sent to the server using AJAX and returned back to `<span id="userstring"></span>`. Whatever was typed in the textarea, it is displayed in the span.
Everything works fine, but... When a user enters tags with a text, for example **<b>hello</b>**, it displays the bold word hello instead of **<b>hello</b>**.

So, the goal is to make THE MINIMUM CHANGES of the typed string, so it is displayed in span EXACTLY the same way as it was typed.

I decided the problem are < and > symbols, so my plan is replace them with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. In the span area will looks the same way as it was typed. Also, I should care of & symbol so when user types `'&gt;'` it looks `&gt;`, that's why & should be replaced with `&amp;`.
Is there anything else I should take care of? 
I don't insert a string into the mysql db, so I don't take any precautions of ' etc. But, I work with that string so I want to keep minimum changes of the string. Replacing &, < and > only are OK. Did I forget something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

```
<php
$string = '<b>bold text</b>';
echo htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8"); 
?>
```

If you omit `ENT_HTML5`, it will default to `ENT_HTML401 | ENT_COMPAT`. In the above code, `ENT_COMPAT` is overridden so the quote character (`"`) will not be escaped anymore.

Comment: Does `htmlspecialchars` escape ampersands too?

Comment: Yes, it does escape ampersands

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, it also replaces signle and double quotes. I don't think they are bad symbols to display in the <span> area (that's not a text area, where " will finish the string). The more symbols I replace, the more work I have to do to analyze the string user typed. Do I really need htmlspecialchars for the task I've described? For textarea " should be replaced. For the span - why?

Comment: In those cases switch ENT_HTML5 with ENT_NOQUOTES

Comment: John, thank you. In this case only &, < and > are replaced. Am I right? So, htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8") is actually the same for UTF-8 (everything is UTF-8) as 3 replacements of & with &amp ; < with &lt ; and > with &gt ; , but performance, and nothing else. Am I right?

Comment: You can also use [`htmlentities()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), which will translate **all** characters with corresponding HTML entities.

Comment: Or use a bbcode parser which will take care all of it. If you don't want to allow tags, just set it off. Nbbc parser is very customizable. Give it a try.